# Comparing two xml files in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file, compare

I have two xml files (a.xml and b.xml) in my file system (iPhone). Now I want to know if these files contain exactly the same data. Most of the time, this comparison would be true, because b.xml is the result of a copyItemAtPath: operation. Unless it is overwritten by newer information.
What would be the most efficient way to compare these files?

1. I could read the contents of the files as strings and then compare the strings
2. I could parse the files and compare some key elements
3. I guess there is a very blunt way, that doesn't need to interpret the file, but allows me to compare on a lower level.

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Thanks ahead

Sjakelien

Update:

I ended up doing this:

```
oldData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:PathToAXML];
newData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:PathToBXML];
```

and then compare it with:

```
[newData isEqualToData:oldData];
```

The question is still: is that more efficient than:

```
oldData = [NSString dataWithContentsOfFile:PathToAXML];
newData = [NSString dataWithContentsOfFile:PathToBXML];

[newData isEqualToString:oldData];
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr contentsEqualAtPath:PathToAXML andPath:PathToBXML])
  NSLog (@"File contents match");
else
  NSLog (@"File contents do not match");
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the list of mismatched xml tags from file manager ?

Answer (score 3):

One alternative to comparing the file contents is to track the file modification date -- if it's later than the date you created the copy, you might assume that it has been updated.

See [fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink:](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink:) in the `NSFileManager` class.

Comment: That is a way to do it. And quite efficient as well, I guess. I will need to store that somewhere though.

Comment: You don't have to store the date somewhere else if you preserve it when doing the copy. I think NSFileManager can do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL filesAreEqual = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:file1] isEqual:[NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:file2]];
```

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Is it possible to get the list of mismatched xml tags from file manager ?

Comment: @SivaprasadKm No. FileManager operates on files and bytes. It has no notion of XML or other structured content.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the information, Is there any way to achieve xml comparison using objective c , I need list of unmatched tags in xml file . Do you know any other methods ?

Comment: @SivaprasadKm Please make an individual post with your question if you can't find this on SO.